# Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _main. Как исправить?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

У меня такая проблема. Есть код, который никак не компилируется, потому что выдает ошибку вот такую:

[image: Ошибка]

Вот сам код:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

#pragma comment(lib, "sfml-graphics-d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "sfml-window-d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "sfml-system-d.lib")

void menu(RenderWindow& window) {
    Texture menuTexture1, menuTexture2, menuTexture3, aboutTexture, menuBackground;
    menuTexture1.loadFromFile("images/111.png");
    menuTexture2.loadFromFile("images/222.png");
    menuTexture3.loadFromFile("images/333.png");
    aboutTexture.loadFromFile("images/about.png");
    menuBackground.loadFromFile("images/about.png");
    Sprite menu1(menuTexture1), menu2(menuTexture2), menu3(menuTexture3), about(aboutTexture), menuBg(menuBackground);
    bool isMenu = 1;
    int menuNum = 0;
    menu1.setPosition(100, 30);
    menu2.setPosition(100, 90);
    menu3.setPosition(100, 150);
    menuBg.setPosition(345, 0);

    //////////////////////////////МЕНЮ///////////////////
    while (isMenu)
    {
        menu1.setColor(Color::White);
        menu2.setColor(Color::White);
        menu3.setColor(Color::White);
        menuNum = 0;
        window.clear(Color(129, 181, 221));

        if (IntRect(100, 30, 300, 50).contains(Mouse::getPosition(window))) { menu1.setColor(Color::Blue); menuNum = 1; }
        if (IntRect(100, 90, 300, 50).contains(Mouse::getPosition(window))) { menu2.setColor(Color::Blue); menuNum = 2; }
        if (IntRect(100, 150, 300, 50).contains(Mouse::getPosition(window))) { menu3.setColor(Color::Blue); menuNum = 3; }

        if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left))
        {
            if (menuNum == 1) isMenu = false;//если нажали первую кнопку, то выходим из меню 
            if (menuNum == 2) { window.draw(about); window.display(); while (!Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape)); }
            if (menuNum == 3) { window.close(); isMenu = false; }

        }

        window.draw(menuBg);
        window.draw(menu1);
        window.draw(menu2);
        window.draw(menu3);

        window.display();
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Comment: и где же Ваша функция main?

Comment: @KoVadim этот код я брал из интернета.

Comment: Нельзя просто так взять произвольный кусок кода и надеяться, что он будет работать. Этот кусок кода просто кусок кода. Вам нужно как минимум дописать функцию main, в которой будет инициализация sfml, и другой полезный код, который вызовет код выше.

Comment: @KoVadim дописал в конце просто int main() {}, теперь ошибок нет, запускается, но пишет, что "завершена работа с кодом 0"

Comment: логично. Если код не вызывать, то он и не будет работать.

Comment: Да, все так. Вызываю код: int main() {
 menu();
} но ошибка в том, что menu() требует аргументы

Comment: ну так правильно, создайте sfml окно и все будет